# Does JRuby Handle Time.new and Timezones Properly?

Tags: ruby, time, jruby

I'm unable to use Ruby's `Time.new` syntax properly in JRuby, even though this works in other Ruby versions as described in the docs. The behavior is different in every way and in some ways, I believe, is incorrect. I have done some research online and it doesn't seem like this is well-known.

Before I go through the hassle of fixing this or submitting to the JRuby group, I want to make sure I'm not being dumb. So to compare, I'll use a basic example of very different behavior.

In JRuby:

```
jruby-1.6.8 :007 > JRUBY_VERSION
 => "1.6.8"
jruby-1.6.8 :008 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "1.9.2"
jruby-1.6.8 :009 > Time.new(2012, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, '+09:00')
 => 2012-10-11 00:00:00 -0400
jruby-1.6.8 :010 > Time.new(2012, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, '+9:00')
 => 2012-10-11 00:00:00 -0400
```

In Ruby:

```
1.9.2p320 :002 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "1.9.2"
1.9.2p320 :003 > Time.new(2012, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, '+09:00')
 => 2012-10-11 00:00:00 +0900
1.9.2p320 :004 > Time.new(2012, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, '+9:00')
 ArgumentError: "+HH:MM" or "-HH:MM" expected for utc_offset
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

ruby has a lot of undocumented behavior. because of that there are a some differences between all the runtimes.

one project that tries to document all the special parts is [RubySpec](http://rubyspec.org/).

you could go here and see if your example is well documented: https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/time/new_spec.rb

Comment: Actually, I think that project is meant to document a specification that all rubies should follow. I found the spec and ran this statement: `Time.new(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, "+05:30").utc_offset # => -18000` and the spec says `should == 19800` so it would fail in this case. Good find!

Comment: @WattsInABox it actually started because of all the "odd" parts